# The best and cleanest way to return a value that depends on an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a lot of code that is structured similar to the one below. There are many Observables or ReplaySubjects. If I want to retrieve from HTML template a value contained in the observable, what is the best way to do that? In special cases, parameters from the template are also included.

```
public config$ = new ReplaySubject<Config>(1);

public getValue(foo: number): number {
  this.config$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((config) => {
     // something like return config.value + foo;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to not use `subscribe` whenever possible, because then you have to also manage unsubscribing from the observable. The best practice is to pipe the observable and then use the `async` pipe in your template. You can also use `*ngIf="config$ | async as config"` to set the `config` variable in your template to the latest value from the observable.

In your controller

```
public value$ = this.config$.pipe(take(1), map(config => config.x));
```

And then in your template

```
Value x from the config: {{ value$ | async }}
```

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgf7bz) for a working example.